# How to create columns of icons and contact information in a Bootstrap list group?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a project which is similar to the snippet below, except that it includes Material Design icons as described in https://materialdesignicons.com/getting-started.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">      
      
      <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
      <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <i class="mdi mdi-map-marker"></i>
          <div>Av. St. Andreu 116, 08392 St. Andreu de Llavaneres, Spain</div>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <i class="mdi mdi-phone"></i>
          +34 937927406
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item">
          <i class="mdi mdi-email"></i>
          <a href=mailto:ralf@peek.solutions>ralf@peek.solutions</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
```

With the icons, it looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, the icon is just 'a part of the text', I suppose because it is an inline element, and putting the address text in a `div` doesn't change this.

I would like to alter this appearance such that it looks more like a table so that when the address wraps to a new line it is left-aligned with the previous line. However, I'd still like to use Bootstrap 4's [`.list-group-flush`](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/) for the 'row layout'.

What would be the best way to approach this? Should I make the `li` a flex box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do so in pure bootstrap. Setting a negative margin for the `i` is a bad practice. Instead, you should remove the padding of `li` elements.

```css
 /* You may not need this line if you use material-design-icon */
.fas {
  line-height: 1.5 !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.7/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-4 mx-auto">
      <ul class="list-group ">
        <li class="list-group-item border-left-0 border-right-0 d-flex pl-0">
          <i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt"></i>
          <span class="pl-3">Av. St. Andreu 116, 08392 St. Andreu de Llavaneres, Spain</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item border-left-0 border-right-0 d-flex pl-0">
          <i class="fas fa-phone"></i>
          <span class="pl-3">+34 937927406</span>
        </li>
        <li class="list-group-item border-left-0 border-right-0 border-bottom-0 d-flex pl-0">
          <i class="fas fa-envelope"></i>
          <a class="pl-3" href=mailto:ralf@peek.solutions>ralf@peek.solutions</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I indeed managed to get the desired layout by making the `li` a flex box. Adding `div` elements to all the text,

```
  <p>Contact us and we'll get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
  <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <i class="mdi mdi-map-marker"></i>
      <div>Av. St. Andreu 116, 08392 St. Andreu de Llavaneres, Spain</div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <i class="mdi mdi-phone"></i>
      <div>+34 937927406<div>
    </li>
    <li class="list-group-item">
      <i class="mdi mdi-email"></i>
      <div><a href=mailto:ralf@peek.solutions>ralf@peek.solutions</a><div>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

and adding the following CSS,

```
li.list-group-item {
  display: flex;
}

li.list-group-item i {
  margin-left: -20px;
}

li.list-group-item div {
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

makes the contact info look like this:

[image]